# Carousel that display 1 card at at time in Microsoft's Bot Framework

Tags: azure, carousel, botframework, bots

Is there a way to implement horizontal carousel that displays 1 card at at time in Microsoft's Bot Framework? I want to show only 1 card at a time in the webchat window. Currently it displays all the cards at the same time that fit into the webchat window.

Comment: Add more context please: which channel are you talking about? Webchat? What do you mean by "move 1 card at a time", because it's already moving 1 card at a time in webchat. It looks like, based on a last sentence, that your wish is to "display" only 1 card at a time, that's not a "move 1 card at a time" problem

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It's for webchat. I have edited my question.

Comment: Just to be sure: webchat window = using the webchat provided by Microsoft? https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

Comment: Yes, I am using the webchat control code provided by microsoft.

Comment: I think you would need to fork the webchat control, and modify the internals: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat